# How fast can muscle fibers relax

Tags: muscles

I can find a great deal of information about how muscles contract, and how we divide them up into fast twitch and slow twitch and so forth.  However, I can't seem to find anything on how fast a muscle fiber can relax.

How fast can a contracted muscle fiber stop providing force when the motor neuron stops innervating it?

Comment: To clarify, are you sure you mean to ask what happens when a "motor neuron stops innervating" a muscle? Or do you mean to ask about the normal physiologic process of muscle relaxation.

Comment: I thought they were phrasings for the same thing, but perhaps I used the wrong term.  A physical example of what I mean:  I am doing a bicep curl.  At a point near the top of the curl, I relax my muscle as much as possible and let the weight (and my arm) fall.  I'm interested in how quickly my muscle can stop resisting that falling movement.